# How to set fixed width for middle column content?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using the default [hero unit](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html) example I have a customized 3 column layout:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="span4"></div>
<div class="span4"></div>
<div class="span4"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

It shows up as:

[image]

But I really want the middle content to be a fixed width...something like (cut paste photoshop for literary content):

How can I resize the middle content to be fixed?  Also interested in how the left and right can be fixed as well?

[image]

Code (less stock from bootstrap hero default example):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="span4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.  cursus commodo, tortor ma</p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="span4">
<div class="row"    >
      <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. </p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="span4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the span counts add up to 12, you can size them however you like. Your screenshot looks like either 3:6:3 or 2:8:2:

**3:6:3**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2:8:2**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span2"></div>
    <div class="span8"></div>
    <div class="span2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...neither of those work with the above contents, however.

Answer (score 0):

Try a float left for all, and set the middle column to have a width attribute. You could also just place them into a table as a container, and then set the tree td columns width.

I am hoping this is what you needed, as I don't want to just tie up response space...  lol   Happy coding.